# Confused about inheritance when using the general sibling combinator "~"(tilde)

Tags: css

So nothing happens when I try to color list items in an unordered list using the general sibling combinator:

http://jsfiddle.net/bkbehpv0/

```css
p {
  color: blue
}
h1 ~ li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1> Title of site </h1>
<p> Text in the site </p>
<p> Second paragraphy </p>
<ul>My list
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

But a `span` inside of a paragraph colors with no problems at all:

http://jsfiddle.net/93khsvbn/

```css
p {
  color: blue
}
h1 ~ p span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1> Title of site </h1>
<p> Text in the site </p>
<p> Second paragraphy <span> heyo </span></p>
<ul>My list
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Sooo... is the `span` on equal footing with the paragraph when it comes to inheritance even though it's nested inside of the paragraph? Why? 
I can't seem to find a thorough source from which I could learn about inheritance.

Also, just as an aside... how do I style the title of an unordered list without styling the list items? Do I HAVE to assign an identifier to the `ul`?
If I style the `ul` the list items will inherit that styling as well.

Comment: sibling is not equal with child. your selector should be `h1 ~ ul > li`. this is because the ul is the sibling and the li are childs of the ul tag.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a note for future reference, all the relevant code should be included in the question itself, if the JS Fiddle links were to die the question would lose its context. I've moved the code into Stack Snippets this time, please consider doing the same for any future questions.

Answer (score 4):

**In your first example (`h1 ~ li`) you are saying:**
Find any `li` which are **siblings to** and **preceded by** a `h1`. As the `li` belong to a `ul` this rule is not matched.

**The second example (`h1 ~ p span`) you are saying:**
Find any `span`s which are **children to** `p` which is a **sibling to** and **preceded by** a `h1`. So the rule is matched.

**To get the first rule to match you should instead use `h1 ~ ul li`. This effectively says:**
Find any `li`s which are **children to** `ul` which is a **sibling to** and **preceded by** a `h1`.

```css
p {
  color: blue
}
h1 ~ ul li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1> Title of site </h1>
<p>Text in the site</p>
<p>Second paragraphy <span> heyo </span></p>
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

It should also be noted that the text "My List" is not valid in the `ul`, it should be surrounded by `li` tags. To differentiate it from the other `li` you could either:

- Add a class: `<li class="heading">My List</li>`
- Move it outside the list: `<h2>My List</h2><ul>`
- Use the `first-child` selector: `li:first-child {color:green;}`

```css
p {
  color: blue
}
li:first-child {
  color:green;
}
h1 ~ ul li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1> Title of site </h1>
<p>Text in the site</p>
<p>Second paragraphy <span> heyo </span></p>
<ul>
  <li>My List</li>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Joshua K said, the `<h1>` is sibling (meaning in the same dom level) as `<ul>`. So as said, you can access a sibling's children like this

`h1 ~ ul > li`

I don't know if there is a complete inheritance guide but you can read about CSS selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and consequently learn about the dom inheritance and element relations.

As for your final question, there is no header in a `<ul>`. In your example `"My list"` is just plain text. You can style it with two ways.

1) (the bad way) style the whole `<ul>` and the overide the attributes in the `<li>` elements.

2) wrap your title around an element e.g. `<span>My List</span>` and apply style in `ul>span`